# Is this Partial Differential Equation likely to be unsolvable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following partial differential equation (PDE) of $f(x, y)$:

$$\alpha x^{2} f_{xx} + \beta x f_{x} - \gamma f - \delta y f_y + \eta f^{2} + \theta f f_y y + \lambda + \kappa x^v y^w = 0$$

It is the terms $\eta f^{2} + \theta f f_y y + \lambda$ which make this equation difficult to solve. If they were absent, the equation would reduce to the PDE equivalent of the Cauchy-Euler equation and would have a fairly straightforward particular solution of the form $\omega x^v y^w$, where $$\omega= \frac{\kappa}{\left(\delta w + \gamma \right) - \beta v - \alpha v \left(v-1 \right)}.$$

I have not been able to find a solution when the terms $\eta f^{2} + \theta f f_y y + \lambda$ are included. Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Is it likely to have a closed-form solution?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tiny suggestion: while it may be coming from the origin of the problem, the near conflation between dependent and independent variables in your PDE leaves it confusing at first glance. Consider separating out into something like $f$ for the independent and $x,z$ (or even $x,y$) for the dependent variables, or $Y$ for the former and $s,t$ for the latter. (And related, '$d$' is always a little loaded as a parameter name when you have differentials running around)

Comment: Thanks Steven, it should be a bit easier to understand now.